# Is it possible to use scoped variant of transmute and still keep first column in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

**Question**

I use time-series data regularly. Sometimes, I would like to transmute an entire data frame to obtain some data frame of growth rates, or shares, for example.

When using `transmute` this is relatively straight-forward. But when I have a lot of columns to transmute and I want to keep the date column, I'm not sure if that's possible.

Below, using the `economics` data set, is an example of what I mean.

**Example**

```
library(dplyr)    
economics %>% 
  transmute(date, 
            pce * 10, 
            pop * 10, 
            psavert * 10)

# A tibble: 574 x 4
date       `pce * 10` `pop * 10` `psavert * 10`
<date>          <dbl>      <dbl>          <dbl>
1 1967-07-01       5067    1987120            126
2 1967-08-01       5098    1989110            126
3 1967-09-01       5156    1991130            119
4 1967-10-01       5122    1993110            129
5 1967-11-01       5174    1994980            128
6 1967-12-01       5251    1996570            118
7 1968-01-01       5309    1998080            117
8 1968-02-01       5336    1999200            123
9 1968-03-01       5443    2000560            117
10 1968-04-01       5440    2002080            123
# ... with 564 more rows
```

Now, using `transmute_at`. The below predictably removes `date` in the `.vars` argument, but I haven't found a way of removing `date` and reintroducing it in `.funs` such that the resulting data frame looks as it does above. Any ideas?

```
economics %>% 
  transmute_at(.vars = vars(-c(date, uempmed, unemploy)), 
               .funs = list("trans" = ~ . * 10))

# A tibble: 574 x 3
pce_trans pop_trans psavert_trans
<dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1  5067 1987120     126
2  5098 1989110     126
3  5156 1991130     119
4  5122 1993110     129
5  5174 1994980     128
6  5251 1996570     118
7  5309 1998080     117
8  5336 1999200     123
9  5443 2000560     117
10  5440 2002080     123
# ... with 564 more rows
```

Comment: Have a doubt , do you need the column names to be changed to `_trans` or as in the first case `pop * 10`

Comment: @akrun Thanks. Yes, as you see, I made a slight edit. I added a suffix to the call. Depending on my specific task, transmute doesn't always apply the calculation to all columns without adding a suffix. Not sure why. In my real word attempt, I am calculating a share and so I reference one of the columns. When I do that, I get the above issue and it doesn't work without the suffix. I tried to incorporate the suffix into your answer, but without success. Could you add that in?

Comment: I added that part with `rename_at` because if I do `list(trans = ~ if(is.numeric(.)) .*10 else .)` it adds `trans` to the 'Date' column as well which you don't need

Comment: I maybe misunderstanding but why can't use `mutate_at` on selected columns and then `select` only the required columns. Like : `economics %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(pce:psavert), ~. * 10) %>%
  select(date:psavert)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah That's what I've been doing, but I'm trying to generalize it. I need to add a suffix to the column names to distinguish them for the occasions I need to rejoin them to other data and because I want to use this on many databases with varying column names, I'd like to avoid the last `select` step by dropping everything that is being transformed right away.

Comment: You can do `economics %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(pce:psavert), list(trans = ~. * 10)) %>% 
  select(date, ends_with('trans'))` which is same as your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, that's a good point. It gets to the same place. I also asked the question in part out of sheer curiosity as to how accomplishing the task with `transmute` was possible. I've actually been wondering how to do it for a couple months and only recently had the time to get around to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `if/else` inside the function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(economics)
economics %>% 
    transmute_at(vars(date:psavert), ~ if(is.numeric(.)) .* 10 else .)
# A tibble: 574 x 4
#  date         pce     pop psavert
#   <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 1967-07-01  5067 1987120     126
# 2 1967-08-01  5098 1989110     126
# 3 1967-09-01  5156 1991130     119
# 4 1967-10-01  5122 1993110     129
# 5 1967-11-01  5174 1994980     128
# 6 1967-12-01  5251 1996570     118
# 7 1968-01-01  5309 1998080     117
# 8 1968-02-01  5336 1999200     123
# 9 1968-03-01  5443 2000560     117
#10 1968-04-01  5440 2002080     123
# … with 564 more rows
```

---

If we need to change the column names selectively, can do this after the `transmute_at`

```
library(stringr)
economics %>% 
    transmute_at(vars(date:psavert), ~ if(is.numeric(.)) .* 10 else .) %>%
    rename_at(vars(-date), ~ str_c(., '_trans'))
# A tibble: 574 x 4
#   date       pce_trans pop_trans psavert_trans
#   <date>         <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1 1967-07-01      5067   1987120           126
# 2 1967-08-01      5098   1989110           126
# 3 1967-09-01      5156   1991130           119
# 4 1967-10-01      5122   1993110           129
# 5 1967-11-01      5174   1994980           128
# 6 1967-12-01      5251   1996570           118
# 7 1968-01-01      5309   1998080           117
# 8 1968-02-01      5336   1999200           123
# 9 1968-03-01      5443   2000560           117
#10 1968-04-01      5440   2002080           123
# … with 564 more rows
```

If we are changing the column names in all the selected columns in `transmute_at` use `list(trans =`

```
economics %>% 
   transmute_at(vars(date:psavert), list(trans = ~if(is.numeric(.)) .* 10 else .))
```

Comment: There we go. Unquoting "trans" fixed it for me. Working now. Thanks!